# Python MySQL update statement does not work

Tags: python, mysql, sql-update

I try to perform a simple update statement in python 2.7 but it won't work at all. I hope someone can show me the mistake:

```
import MySQLdb
import datetime

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",    # your host, usually localhost
                     user="root",         # your username
                     passwd="",  # your password
                     db="******")        # name of the data base

cur = db.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM data")

for row in cur.fetchall():
    id_row = str(row[0])
    date = str(row[1])
    new_date = date[:-2]
    new_date += "00"
    cur.execute("UPDATE data SET date={0} WHERE ID={1}".format(new_date, id_row))

db.close()
```

The script should take the date as unix timestamp from the database cut off the 
 last  two numbers, replace them with 00 and update the row in the database. 
The code to replace the numbers works but the update process does not. 
It show no error message and exits with code 0.

I have no idea where I made the mistake. Can anyone help?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does ID need to be wrapped in quotes?

Comment: Try a db.commit() before you close the connection?

Comment: Try casting `row[0]` to `int` instead of `str` and `db.commit()` might help as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shame on me!

The error was the missing db.commit().

Thank you for your hints! :)

Answer (score 3):

```
         import pymysql
         import datetime

         db = pymysql.connect(host="localhost",    # your host, usually localhost
                 user="root",         # your username
                 passwd="",  # your password
                 db="******")        # name of the data base
         cur.execute("SELECT * FROM data")

         cur = db.cursor()
         cur.execute("UPDATE data SET date={0} WHERE ID={1}".format(new_date, id_row))
         db.commit()
         ##### pymysql is module
         ##sudo apt-get install python-pip  
         ####sudo pip install PyMySQL
```